# TableFooterView disappears when user interacts

Tags: ios, swift, user-interface

I have 2 textFields in my tableFooterView. When I change focus from one to another, my tableFooterView disappears.

```
        let tableFooterView = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("BasketFooter", owner: self, options: nil)?[0] as! BasketCinemaFooter
        tableFooterView.setUp(sum: (self.cinemaRestoranFooter?.summ)!, dostavka: (self.cinemaRestoranFooter?.dostavka)!, total: (self.cinemaRestoranFooter?.total)!, cinema: (self.cinemaRestoranFooter?.name)!)
        tableFooterView.delegate = self
        self.tableView.tableFooterView = tableFooterView
```

here is the code how I add tableFooterView. How to fix the problem?

My tableFooterView is static, and is not sectionFooter. It's footer for the whole table. I cant import image :( 
When my viewController loads, everything is OK, when I tap the first textField, it's OK, but when I tap another textField, tableFooterView disappears

Comment: Please decribe more details about your problem and also look how to write a good question: [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I solved the problem. My xib was created as UITableViewCell. You shoud you UIView for tableFooterView.

Comment: That is good to hear, but please describe the problem in more details, as other people will reach this question.